# Map Reduce in Mongo, Convert mongo query to php mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I had a query in mongo which looks like

```
db.Table_Name.group({
   "key": { "Camp": true },
   "initial": { "Clicks": 0 },
   "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
       prev.Clicks = prev.Clicks + obj.Clicks-0;
   },
   "cond": { "Date": { $gte: "2012-10-26", $lte: "2012-10-28" } }
});
```

I want to use this code in php. I tried all the possible ways. Can any one help me out from this problem. Even I followed this http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php Please any one help me out.

I tried this

```
$reduce = new MongoCode(
    "function(obj, prev) {prev.Clicks = prev.Clicks + obj.Clicks-0;}"
);

$result = $db_1->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => 'Collection_Name',
    'key'       => array("Camp" => true),   
    'initial'  => array('Clicks' => 0), 
    'reduce' => $reduce,                
    'cond' => array(
        'Date' => array('$gte' => '2010-07-12' , '$lte' => '2013-07-12')
     ), 
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [MongoCollection::group](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.group.php)? For your example, it might look something like this (not tested).

```
$keys = array("Camp" => 1);
$initial = array("Clicks" => 0);
$reduce = "function(obj, prev) {prev.Clicks = prev.Clicks + obj.Clicks-0;}";
$condition = array(
    'Date' => array('$gte' => '2010-07-12', '$lte' => '2013-07-12')
);
$result = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce, $condition);
```

Also, you should try to embrace the MongoDB terminology, i know it's just an example, but `Table_Name` should be `Collection_Name` as [MongoDb does not have tables](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#do-mongodb-databases-have-tables).

Comment: tables; collections...meh not much difference to the end user tbh, if he is happy calling them tables then I don't really see the problem

Comment: Hi Sammaye, Yes, you're right there is no real 'problem'... however, using the wrong terminology is only gonna cause confusion for your brain in the long run. Not to mention how you'll look in a meeting if you use the wrong terminology, or worse, an interview.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Can you say how to sort it by Date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the group command here but it is:

- Slow
- Basically a Map Reduce
- JavaScript
- Normally does not work with sharding (some people have made it)
- Is deprecated in favour of the aggregation framework

Instead a better option would be to use the aggregation framework:

```
$mongo->db->collection->aggregate(array(
    array('$match'=>array('date'=>array('$gte' => '2010-07-12','$lte' => '2013-07-12'))),
    array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'$Camp', 'sum_clicks'=>array('$sum'=>'$Clicks')))
));
```